# Flexbox content spills out of container. Chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I began designing a mobile first website. First ever paid website!! I'm not using Bootstrap until I master flexbox, so don't say use bootstra//templates :) I'm having problems as my site looks good when viewed mobile, but looks like crap when viewed on a large screen.

A specific problem I'm having is a 2x7 row/column grid, the words spill out of the container, but fit fine with mobile view on.

This is not specific to chrome.

How do I make flexbox mobile friendly? Is it simply flex-grow/shrink? I find it odd that my divs need to shrink as the screen gets larger, and they def shouldn't get any bigger..and If I make the white portion of the div a larger VH it will also "fix" it. But that seems counter-intuitive...On a bigger screen I must make the container an even greater % just to fit the same size font??

Or is this a media query thing...and if so what would it be? Media Query's making fonts smaller seems wrong, I'm looking for the best way/best practice not a work around if possible :)

MY CODE:

```
 HTML5:


  <div class="s2-row" >

        <div class="s2-columns center">Talent Management</div> 
        <div class="s2-columns center">Athlete & Artist Development</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Booking Talent</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Negotiating Booking Rights</div> 
        <div class="s2-columns center">STravel Logistics</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Sound</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Lights</div> 
        <div class="s2-columns center">Backline Equipment</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Venue Selection</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Event Set-Up & Contracting</div> 
        <div class="s2-columns center">Sponsor Mangement</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Promotional Negotations</div>
        <div class="s2-columns center">Complete Event Presentations</div> 
        <div class="s2-columns center">Rider Requirements</div>
        <div class="s2-row2 center">As well as many other event specific 
needs</div>

    </div>


 CSS3:


  div.s2-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

 div.s2-columns {
     flex-basis: 50%;
 }

  h3.s2-row2 {
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 30px;
}

.center {
    align-self: center;
}
```

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX6oC.jpg)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4d3z.png)

Thank you in advance!

(2nd pic is how it looks on mobile)

Comment: I think your problem is with the container (not with the content that you provided in the question: HTML & CSS. We can't replicate the problem with that). Try setting a media query for your container on desktop with a  `min-height`

Comment: which container? The <div class="s2-row'>  ?? Thanks I know that'll defintely work! Is that the best practice/ "correct" way to deal with this problemo? Thank you for reading boyd!

Answer (score 0):

I settled with simply making the container elements vh bigger. I think I could've messed with flex-shrink/grow or media queries as well but I kept it simple.